# linux command line, rearrange djvu file to facilitate book index use in reader

Tags: linux, command-line, djvu

To read books that have an index on my laptop or ereader, I like to make the first page in the reader/viewer be the first page of the text, so that the book's Index page numbers correspond directly with the reader's page numbers. This involves removing some pages from the front of the file and transferring them to the end of the file.

With a pdf this is very simple, e.g.

```
mutool merge -o F2.pdf F1.pdf 18-460 F1.pdf 1-17
```

But with djvu the process seems more complex, requiring perhaps

1. Extract from the main.djvu with `mkdir a/ && djvmcvt -i F1.djvu a a-index.djvu`
2. Renumber the extracted djvus to put them in the order I want
3. Convert them back to a single djvu with `djvm -c *.djvu F2.djvu`

Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

K J's suggestion to double the file then delete from either end of the doubled file seemed reasonable Until I discovered that you get to delete 1 page at a time from a file (see man djvm).

My own idea of presenting the individual files in the order I wanted them to be produced a persistent error, that the name of the last file in the list was too long, and no output file was ever produced.

Finally, I settled on this very simple solution:

`ddjvu -format=pdf -quality=80 F1.djvu F1.pdf`

`mutool merge -o F2.pdf F1.pdf 18-460 F1.pdf 1-17`